# Android/Java Beginner: Overriding ArrayAdapter's getView

Tags: android

Firstly I am new to android and Java so this is a beginners question.

I have some code that overrides the ArrayAdapter's getView method. Here is the code

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
   TextView label = (TextView)convertView;
   if (convertView == null) {
      convertView = new TextView(ctxt);
      label = (TextView)convertView;
   }
   label.setText(items[position]);
   return (convertView);
}
```

My question is: why does `label.setText(items[position]);` affect the `convertView` return value? How are they related / linked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TextView label = (TextView)convertView;` doesn't set label to be a copy of `convertView`,

it is `convertView`. It's a reference to the same object. So when you do

`label.setText(items[position]);`, it does it on convertView.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code `convertView` and `label` are two variables that both reference the same `TextView` object.  Whatever you do with either variable will be reflected in the `TextView` object they reference.

Answer (score 0):

```
TextView label = (TextView)convertView;
```

that both reference the same object(reference of label =reference of convertView),so ,convertView will be reflected by the label object.